# How are rounded numbers stored in R?

Tags: r, number-formatting

I have found a lot of information on this online, but I haven't been able to find anything that *exactly* answers my question. My issue does not have to do with the presentation of the numbers, but instead the calculations and storage underneath the presentation.

The issue is with floating points in R. I wish to truncate them; however, I want to make sure I am storing them correctly after they are truncated.

The problem is: I have a dataset where I am trying to compare the difference between different numbers to any threshold I would like (exact to 2 decimal places - i.e. 0.00, 0.05, and 1.00.). I want to make sure when I test the difference to exactly zero that it is testing exactly the correct difference and there is not a storage problem going on behind that I am unaware of.

So far, I have tried:

(1) `round` (and testing against 0, and very small values like `1e-10`)

(2) multiplying by 100 and `as.integer`

These calculations come up with different answers when I calculate the percentage of observations that have a difference greater than my chosen threshold in my dataset.

In short, it would be great to know how to best store the number to get the most accurate result when calculating whether or not the difference is actually 0.

*Note: This needs to work for large datasets.*

Example:

```
dt <- 
      data.table(d = c(0.00, 988.36, 0.00, 2031.46, 0.00), 
                 c = c(0.00, 30.00, 0.00, 2031.46, 0.00), 
                 n = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b"))

dt[, diff := d - c]

dt[, abs_diff := abs(diff)]

dt[, pct_diff := mean(abs_diff == 0, na.rm = TRUE), by = "n"]
```

The last step is the problem, as I continuously get different numbers for `pct_diff` based on the threshold. (For example, `mean(abs_diff <= 1e-10)` and `mean(abs_diff <= 1e-15)` give me different answers).

Comment: You should provide some form of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it more clear what's going on.

Comment: Can you make some examples and the output you want? I don't fully get neither what you mean by `exactly 0` nor your rounding process. When a number is stored correctly? What is the correct difference?

Comment: Sure - I can add an example.

Comment: The results in the example you posted look regular to me. What's wrong with them? Also, you shouldn't compare floating point values. Do your data really care if the difference is 10^-10 or exactly 0?

Comment: I don't care if the data are minutely different - I am just trying to capture the differences correctly. I would like to compare them to the 0.01 value. I am just trying to capture this in the most accurate way - I keep getting different answers based on the methods I use.

Comment: `abs(x - 0.01) < tol` is how you test this for floating point numbers. `col` can be chosen after consulting `help(".Machine")`.

Answer (score 2):

Rounded numbers are stored as `numeric`, i.e., floating point numbers:

```
class(round(1.1))
#[1] "numeric"

class(floor(1.1))
##[1] "numeric"
```

It seems like your are looking for packages that support arbitrary precision numbers, such as package Rmpfr.